# PyQt: mainWindow closed, but process still running

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm writing a Python application with PyQt 5.10.
It seems I have some sort of bug/memory leak, since when I call close() on my MainWindow the process keeps running. After a bit of research and debugging I was able to circumscribe the supposedly faulty code.
This is my main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    matteo = God()
    matteo.runApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Here you will find the runApp function from God class:

```
def runApp(self):
    self.painter = Painter()
    self.dbManager = DBManager()
    self.userInput = UserInput()
    self.excelFile = ExcelFile()
    self.painter.connectToClasses(self, ["god","db","ui"])
    self.excelFile.connectToClasses(self, ["god",])
    self.painter.drawMainWindow()
    self.loadConf()
    self.openDB(True)
    if self.dbManager.error==None:
        self.painter.drawSearchWidget()
    else:
        print("Closed.")
```

The process keeps running when the app is not able to find the configuration file, and so it creates a new one from scratch and it asks the user to select the database which he wants to connect to. This prompts an error message - if the selected file is corrupted or it's not the right format - and I think there might lie my problem.
That's the code:

```
def checkError(self, classType):
    if classType=="db":
        error = self.dbManager.error
    elif classType=="excel":
        error = self.excelFile.error
    if error!=None:
        self.painter.drawError(classType)
        self.userInput.error = self.painter.error.clickedButton()
        self.userInput.error = self.painter.error.buttonRole(self.userInput.error)
        if (self.userInput.error==1):
            self.painter.mainWindow.close()
            return 0
        return 1

 def drawError(self,  classType):
    if (classType=="db"):
        title = "Database"
        error = self.dbManager.error
        otherButton = "Browse"
    elif (classType=="excel"):
        title = "Excel file"
        error = self.excelFile.error
    try:
        self.setErrorText(False, error)
        if error[0]:
            if self.error.icon()!=3:
                self.error.setIcon(3)
            buttons = self.error.buttons()
            for button in buttons:
                if button.text()!="Quit":
                    button.hide()
                    button.deleteLater()
    except AttributeError:
        self.error = QMessageBox()
        self.setErrorText(True, error)
        if (error[0]):
            self.error.setIcon(3)
        else:
            self.error.setIcon(2)
            self.error.addButton(otherButton, self.error.AcceptRole)
        self.error.addButton("Quit",  self.error.RejectRole)
    self.error.setWindowTitle(title)
    self.error.exec()
```

If the user clicks the quit button on the error window, the function closes main window and return 0. The other functions return and the application prints closed on the console. But the process keeps going.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of resolved this issue calling sys.exit() instead of printing closed.

It's a brute force solution to say the least, but I needed to deliver the application fast and I had no time to debug it.
I guess this sad story will end here.